# Beautiful Soup, Python and the swedish characters ÅÄÖ

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape a Swedish web page. On the web page, the information I want to extract looks like this:

```
"Öhman Företagsobligationsfond"
```

When I print the information from the Python script it looks like this:

```
"Ã&ndash;hman FÃ¶retagsobligationsfond"
```

I'm new to Python and I have searched for answers and tried using `# -- coding: utf-8 --` in the beginning of the code but it does not work.

I'm thinking of moving from Sweden to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you checked if the HTML text you're parsing (before beautifulsoup) decoded correctly by python? It might be that the source is not UTF-8, or it is UTF-8 but was decoded as something else. 

Also, if you share your code, you're more likely to get useful assistance.

Comment: Good comment. I have checked the original HTML text and it looks like charset=iso-8859-1 is used. What do I do then?

Comment: You can use `string.decode` on the original HTML text to fix. (Or use beautifulsoup's `from_encoding` parameter, which does something quite similar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `# -- coding: utf-8 --` you only specify the encoding of the source code document. The page that you are parsing has probably declared a faulty encoding (or none at all), and therefore Beautiful Soup fails. Try to specify the encoding when building the soup. Here's a small example:

```python
markup = '''
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Övriga fakta</title>
        <meta charset="latin-1" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Öhman Företagsobligationsfond</h1>
        <p>Detta är en svensk sida.</p>
    </body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
print soup.find('h1')

try:
    # Version 4
    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, from_encoding='utf-8')
except TypeError:
    # Version 3
    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, fromEncoding='utf-8')

print soup.find('h1')
```

The output from this is:

```html
<h1>Ãhman FÃ¶retagsobligationsfond</h1>
<h1>Öhman Företagsobligationsfond</h1>
```

In Beautiful Soup 4, the parameter is `from_encoding`, while in version 3, the parameter is `fromEncoding`.

Comment: Also make sure your terminal can display utf-8 characters, otherwise it will appear that nothing is working because your terminal is not utf-8 compatible.

Comment: As I wrote above the HTML text is using iso-8859-1. Do not know how to handle this but I have tried. soup = BeautifulSoup(content,from_encoding="iso-8859-8") but then I got an error "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'from_encoding'. I have also changed "iso-8859-8" to 'iso-8859-8' but it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, wrote 8859-8 when it should have been 8859-1.

Comment: Same error if i use: soup = BeautifulSoup(content, from_encoding='utf-8')

Comment: @Ahlden: Try changing the parameter to `fromEncoding` or updating Beautiful Soup to version 4. I'm guessing you're using version 3 of Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Great! This solve the issue but I now got another error when I loop through the names with swedish characters "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 17: ordinal not in range(256)" and it is when this sting is extracted "Skandia European – General Electric". Any ideas?

Comment: Are you really using `utf-8` when creating the soup? The en dash (–) is not a part of `latin-1`, so naturally it fails to encode it.

Comment: I believe so. This is the exact code when I'm creating the soup content = urllib.urlopen(address).read() soup = BeautifulSoup(content, fromEncoding='utf-8') When I extract "Skandia European – General Electric" and print it or use it in a SQL statement I get the error. Good that you ask questions because this is new to me and I might do a lot of simple errors.

Comment: @McFjodor: I have tried to use yout example above. To make the script run I added this in the beginning: #!/usr/bin/python # -- coding: utf-8 -- from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup' and the output from both print statements are "<h1>├ûhman F├Âretagsobligationsfond</h1>".Why do I don't get the same result as you?

Comment: The error message has changed a little bit due to small changes and is now "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 17: character maps to <undefined>". Any ideas? This was tricky...

Comment: I have now checked the output and knows that the the character Å is handled the right way. I believe that it is only the character u'\u2013' which needs to be fixed. As I wrote above the HTML text looks like it is using iso-8859-1. Please help me so I can move forward with my project!

Comment: Here is the complete error code: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ExtractValuesUtv.py", line 46, in <module>
    print txtInstr
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 17: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Ahlden: Can we take this discussion in chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19400/room-for-mcfjodor-and-ahlden

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19470/discussion-between-ahlden-and-mcfjodor)